# Html to this code - PHP Form

Tags: php, html, forms, reference, contacts

I am new to php and my webhost does not allow me to run simple php form available on http://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php

they guided me to a knowledge base and asked me to use this php code i tried to intergrate this with my current form and it just doesn't send any email

Here is the php code:

```
<?

$mailto = "xyz@yourdomain.com";
$file = "thanks.htm";
$pcount = 0;
$gcount = 0;
$subject = "Mail from Enquiry Form";

$from = "some-name@yourdomain.com";
while (list($key, $val) = each($_POST)) {
    $pstr = $pstr . "$key : $val \n ";
    ++$pcount;

}
while (list($key, $val) = each($_GET)) {
    $gstr = $gstr . "$key : $val \n ";
    ++$gcount;

}
if ($pcount > $gcount) {
    $message_body = $pstr;
    mail($mailto, $subject, $message_body, "From:" . $from);

    include("$file");
} else {
    $message_body = $gstr;

    mail($mailto, $subject, $message_body, "From:" . $from);
    include("$file");
}
?>
```

Here is the html

http://pastebin.com/Nzq0TCVp

Any suggestions?

Comment: First off, get rid of the & sign in "...to your query & not for marketing..."

Comment: That is the code that they told you to use? Get a better host.

Comment: [Don't reinvent the wheel](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer).

Comment: I know about phpmailer but I preferred if there was a way to make a simple light weight form